# Deduce the Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let V be an inner product space,and suppose that $x$ and $y $ are orthogonal vectors in V.We also know $\left\lVert x+y  \right\rVert^2=\left\lVert x  \right\rVert^2+\left\lVert y  \right\rVert^2$.My question is how can we deduce the pythagorean theorem in $\mathbb R^2$ from it.If possible give geometrical views.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!! in advance.

Comment: R^2 is an inner product space - done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard inner product space with $\mathbb{R^2}$. Then $\left\lVert x  \right\rVert$ is the length of x, $\left\lVert y  \right\rVert$ is the length of y, and $\left\lVert x+y  \right\rVert$ is the length of the diagonal connecting $x$ and $y$. In this case then, $\left\lVert x+y  \right\rVert^2=\left\lVert x  \right\rVert^2+\left\lVert y  \right\rVert^2$ is equivalent to the pythagorean theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: :Thanks!!.Actually,i'd taken the length of x to be IIxII instead of  IIxII^2 that's why i get confused.

Comment: @PKStyles no problem, good luck!

Comment: There does seem to be some confusion here. $||x||$ should indeed be the length of $x$.

Comment: @LeeMosher you are right, thank you. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @PKStyles sorry for the confusion, ||x|| is indeed the length of x.